Union of tuples deconstruction in typescript
While rewriting an old JS file to TypeScript, I ran onto a problem with a function that is supposed to transform data from one format to another, as follows:
https://tsplay.dev/WGgYXW
type DataTypes = {
  type: "typeOne"
  item: number
} | {
  type: "typeTwo",
  item: string
} | {
  type: "typeThree",
  item: unknown
}

// I can't change this function, it is used in more places
const setData = (dataToSet: DataTypes) => dataToSet.item;


// The following function can process only particular types
type ReceivableDataTypes = "typeOne" | "typeTwo"

// I create a type for the tuples that are possible to receive
type IncomingData = {
  [K in ReceivableDataTypes]: [K, Extract<DataTypes, {type: K}>["item"]]
}[ReceivableDataTypes]
// type IncomingData = ["typeOne", number] | ["typeTwo", string]

// as you might guess, I can't change the format of the received data
const handleIncomingData = (...incomingData: IncomingData)=>{
  setData({type: incomingData[0], item: incomingData[1]})
}

handleIncomingData("typeOne", 1)
handleIncomingData("typeTwo", "test")
// this should throw an error
handleIncomingData("typeTwo", 12)

The problem is that while incomingData is typed correctly as a union of arrays, when used to create a new object, the association is broken, and both type and item become just two separate union types:
{
    type: "typeOne" | "typeTwo";
    item: string | number;
}

Breaking further inferring of the created object. I could add a manual assertion of setData({type: incomingData[0], item: incomingData[1]} as DataTypes) which seems like a fairly sensible assumption - but I want to avoid using as. Is there any way to retain the connection between the elements of tuple and properties of the created object, so that it would get instead inferred as the following?
{
  type: "typeOne"
  item: number
} | {
  type: "typeTwo",
  item: string
}


You will have a far easier time using type assertions here, but if you really want to have TS follow this logic you need to refactor your types as described in ms/TS#47109 to look like this playground link. Whether or not you want to or are allowed to do this in practice, that's the official TS way of doing it. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz that actually makes me think that the problem is indeed further down the line than I thought. The problem is that in the real life scenario setData is a react React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<DataTypes>> and as such can't be turned into a generic. I guess that's where the actual problem lies. Thanks for pointing me in a direction.
